# When passing a JavaScript function as a parameter in another function, is it possible to access the other variables passed?

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript function like this:

```
obj.use('hello', function () {
  // Here I want to access the string 'hello'
});
```

Is this at all possible, or are there any good workarounds that I can use?

Comment: Not if `use` don't transmits it. But you should learn about javascript closures : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: In this code as is it is not possible, no. If you rewrote that code slightly or if the `use` method does something in particular that would allow such access, then yes.

Comment: This question should *not* get closed; he's asking for a workaround, and I aim to provide one in an answer

Comment: Is `obj` coming from a specific library?  If so, it might provide such information.

Comment: Everybody voting to close, really what is so hard about realizing that obj is an object and use is a method on that object?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty - You're just making an assumption that the OP has not verified. The question is clearly "Unclear what you're asking" which I and everyone else has chosen.

Comment: `My answer is based on the fact that your usage indicates use as being a method of the object obj` - thats an assumption - `obj` could be from a library, or not in the OP's control.

Comment: OK but still why would you choose to vote to close an question you are also answering

Comment: Because thats the best answer I can give at the moment, should it be closed thats fine, should the OP clarify I can improve the answer.

Comment: Changed fact to assumption in my answer.  It's pretty depressing to me to not have much of a chance of gaining reputation after spending 20 minutes on my answer.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based on the assumption that your usage indicates `use` as being a method of the object `obj`.  In which case the way to achieve your objective is to use the same object to store the first parameter to `obj.use`.

```
  var obj = {
    use: function(greeting, fn) {
        obj.greeting = greeting;
        fn();
    }
  }

  obj.use('hello', function () {
    console.log(obj.greeting); //output: 'hello'
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for not commenting when down-modding

Answer (score 0):

> // Here I want to access the string 'hello'

Well that's easy, you just store the string in a variable whose scope is accessible inside the method:

```
var greeting = 'hello';
obj.use(greeting, function () {
    console.log(greeting); // logs "hello"
});
```